# PHP Array Questions

Tags: php, arrays

Questions in Code;

```
<?php
/*
* @array
*/
$input = array("Neo", "Morpheus", "Trinity", "Cypher", "Tank");
$rand_keys = array_rand($input, 2); //What does the two mean?
echo $input[$rand_keys[1]] . "\n"; //What does the 1 stand for? and Why do I have to define $input again if it was defined in $rand_keys?
?>
```

What do the numbers mean?  Thanks.

EDIT:

I have tried:

```
$input = array("test", "test2", "test3", "test4");
$rand_keys = array_rand($input, 2);
$echo = $input[$rand_keys[0]];
echo $echo;
```

And it shows up to test3.  I only did 2 in the array rand.  Why is it showing 3?

Comment: Maybe you should start by *reading* the manual entry for `array_rand`: http://php.net/array_rand

Comment: @deceze He should start reading this manual: http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/php/php.html

Comment: Thanks but it does not quite answer my questions, like I do not understand the [1] in the echo, and the 2 in the rand keys.  I don't understand how they are different

Comment: See this example http://www.developphp.com/view_lesson.php?v=477

Comment: It randomly picks two elements from $input. And it happens to place test3 in the first element of $rand_keys which is $rand_keys[0].

Answer (score 1):

Well the array_rand function is explained here:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php

So the 2 specifies how many entries you want to pick.

The number 1 stands for the index 1 in the array rand_keys and you aren't defining the input again, you are just accesing a value inside the input array.

Hope this helped!

Comment: Helped.  But what do you mean by `entries`?

Comment: In your array("Neo", "Morpheus", "Trinity", "Cypher", "Tank") the entries are Neo, Morpheus, Trinity, etc.

Comment: I set it to 3 and it is doing four entries, `neo, morpheus, trinity, cypher`, not just `neo, morpheus, trinitity`

Answer (score 0):

Read the manual if you have questions about functions: [`array_rand`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php)

The second argument is described below:

> #### `num_req`
>
> Specifies how many entries you want to pick. Trying to pick more
>   elements than there are in the array will result in an `E_WARNING` level
>   error.

This line of code:

```
echo $input[$rand_keys[1]] . "\n";
```

Prints out the element of `$input` with an index equal to `$rand_keys[1]`, the second element of `$rand_keys`

Answer (score 0):

```
array_rand — Pick one or more random entries out of an array
```

The 'number' denotes the number of random values from the array.

For more refer
http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php

For example:
http://www.developphp.com/view_lesson.php?v=477

Comment: @RyanPartnership please look my answer and check the example.I hope you can clear your doubts from there.

Answer (score 0):

array_rand will give you a number of random entries from an array.

In this case, the 2 specifies that you want two random entries from the array.

The [1] represents the second element in the array. (Arrays elements start at 0)

Comment: @RyanPartnership Ok, I added a comment.  It randomly chooses two elements from $input and places them into $rand_keys.  So it's just random that test3 ended up in the first element of $rand_keys.  Element [0].

Answer (score 0):

The second parameter in array_rand() means:

*Picks one or more random entries out of an array, and returns the key (or keys) of the random entries.*

1 stands for element in array with index 1. In this case it is the second element in array as it is indexed from 0.

You are not defining anything again, you are just printing element from `$input` with the second key from your `$random_keys` array.

Answer (score 0):

`$rand_keys = array_rand($input, 2); //What does the two mean?`

2 means, how many entries you want to pick randomly. You mentioned 2, so 2 random entries will be picked.

`echo $input[$rand_keys[1]] . "\n"; //What does the 1 stand for? and Why do I have to define $input again if it was defined in $rand_keys?`

**What does the 1 stand for?**
`array_rand` returns arrays which contains key, `1` contains second entries returned by `array_rand`.

**Why do I have to define $input again if it was defined in $rand_keys?**
`array_rand` will returns the entries only as `key(s)` not values, If you need the value then you will `$input`.

Answer (score 0):

array_rand function is used to pick one or more random entries out of an array.

In your code `array_rand($input,2)`, 2 is number of entries you want to pick up from `$input` array

Answer to your question

`What does the 1 stand for? and Why do I have to define $input again if it was defined in $rand_keys?`

is

```
array_rand returns an array of random keys.
```

`So to access the value from $input array you need to use it as index only i.e. $rand_key[1] is one of the index of $input that's why you need to mention $input.`